# Can I force a link to open in a specific browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have designed a website using Firefox and am now looking to integrate a softphone into the webpage, but unfortunately it is made with ActiveX, so Firefox won't support it.

I have tried opening my page in IE9, and it looks a mess because I've used CSS3 for a lot of it and haven't coded it for different browsers because we will only be using Firefox within the office.

Is there a way that I can tell my page in Firefox to specifically open a new page in Internet Explorer and just have the softphone in there? Or is there a way to get ActiveX running in Firefox with a plugin or something?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you really should make your website functional on all browsers.

Comment: No, you can't let Firefox open another browser (even not another program): imagine the security risks that such possibilities would imply. BTW, just spotted another [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Comment: Lots of people don't even have Internet Explorer installed. And lots of those that do aren't going to agree to the *Click OK to allow ActiveX control access to anything on your PC* and then also agree to the follow up *Are you sure you want to do this dangerous thing?* dialog.

Comment: Making it functional across other browsers is something for the future, but for now its not important for us. This isnt a webpage that is going to be available to the public, just a few people in an office

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can open a IE window from firefox, but you can easily build a firefox plugin based on your activex using http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/

Comment: I'd be amazed if that wasn't a Windows-only plugin.

Comment: activex is windows only... to make it cross platform he would have to rewrite the whole activex component

Comment: uhm... Good as an answer but very bad as an idea

Answer (score 16):

You can open a link in Microsoft Edge from any browser by adding `microsoft-edge:`  in front of the url in the HREF.

```html
<a href="microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com">EDGE (works)</a>
```

I don't know how to get it to work in other browsers though. My team and I spent quite a bit of time on it and couldn't find a raw HTML/JavaScript solution.

Comment: For me, the link won't open if I'm already on Edge. Is that a normal behavior?

Comment: I can confirm that the link doesn't open for me in Edge as of right now. That's pretty unexpected for me. Let us know if you come up with a solution. I assume an update change something, since it would have been an unacceptable solution for me at the time I was looking at this.

Comment: At the moment, I've checked several articles and I do not find any solid solution. My workaround for the moment will be to add a function to check the browser at the launch of my application.

Comment: It also does not open coming from Chrome

Comment: @mrk Try right-clicking and clicking "Open Link in a new Tab" - it will prompt you to open Edge. With that said, this is not a solution that can be used in prod.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on your exact situation.

If you are targeting multiple users outside a corporate network this is hardly possible to achieve. However, if you are targeting your company's network it's possible to do this using custom protocol.

Your link then would look like: ie://opens_in_ie.com

You'll have to make changes to registry of target computers though. More info about custom protocols is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In most cases, system administrator can do this remotely.

Answer (score 7):

[IETab V2](http://www.ietab.net/) will let you open a tab within Firefox that runs the IE engine.

Once installed, you can force a link to open with IE by formatting the URL or bookmark like this:

```
chrome://ietab2/content/reloaded.html?url=http://domain.com
```

Answer (score 6):

It's somewhat specific, but I created an internal site at work, and I wanted to link to another internal site that only works in IE. To do this, I created/defined my own application protocol in the registry. Then I added to my links the protocol header. This is similar to what apple does when you click a link and it opens iTunes. The downside to this approach, however, is that users will have to install the registry modification for it to work... like I said, it's really a solution for a very specific scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Including double quotation marks around both program location and webpage name will do the trick:

```
"file location.exe"<space>"webpage"
```

Comment: The question is about making Firefox open the link in Internet Explorer. It isn't about the Windows command line

Answer (score -2):

Same answer as from chuck wallace

If you want to start from for example in Internet Explorer, go to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` and create a shortcut to the Desktop.
When you check the properties from this created shortcut, you will see the Target: `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`.

Now you can place the shortcut from the website, behind the Target. It will show something like this: `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` `www.nu.nl`. Or this `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` `https://stackoverflow.com`.
This way it opens IE first and then the website.