# Specify web brower in href tag

Tags: browser, href, default

Is there a way to specify the web browser to be used in a `href` tag ? For instance, I have the following URL and I need it to be opened with Firefox only :

```
<a href="http://vienne.lpo.fr">LPO Vienne</a>
```

Thanks for your advices !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force a link to open in a specific browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881383/can-i-force-a-link-to-open-in-a-specific-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. If it was it would have to work on the assumption the user would have that browser, so even if it was possible it would not be a very good solution.

You could always have a notification on the linked page, explaining the user should use a specific browser, if they are not already. This would be more user friendly and you could provide a link to download etc.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is possible these days - at least in the case of Microsoft Edge.  Check [this](http://www.itworld.com/article/3008858/development/how-to-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks.html) out. Although agree with ProWebMonkey that usability issues still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not true at all. It is possible like this:

A HREF="microsoft-edge:http://www.yoururlgoeshere.com"

the call "microsoft-edge:" before the actual URL will force the link to open in that browser, assuming the browser is installed on the machine.

Comment: I don't think this works! In which system have you seen this working?