# how to open link in internet explorer using html or any browser language?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a new project and I need to open a link in Explorer with a click on button from Chrome or Firefox using any browser language.
I have search a lot and I found this code

I tried this `i-explorer:https://www.google.com`

```
<a class="mscom-link c-call-to-action c-glyph edgedownload" aria-label="Try Microsoft Edge" href="Microsoft-edge:https://microsoftedgewelcome.microsoft.com/?FORM=MK12CD&amp;wt.mc_id=MK12CD" data-bi-name="try now" data-bi-id="n1c1m1r1a3" data-bi-type="text" data-bi-bhvr="TRIALSINITATE"><span class="x-hidden-focus">TRY NOW</span></a>
```

This code open the link in microsoft edge but I want to open it on internet explorer I've taken this code from this https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/microsoft-edge. 
You can try to open microsoft edge. 
Please don't tell me to use extensions I know that.
I think it's possible to do that. Thanks alot.

Comment: No that’s not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I force a link to open in a specific browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881383/can-i-force-a-link-to-open-in-a-specific-browser)

Comment: thanks but you see in https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/microsoft-edge it's open microsoft edge so why I cant use the method on iexplorer please any body can tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do it without a plugin would be to add a protocol handler to the registry on your machine. Edge does it out of the box because it contains one - just like any other application that is capable of opening links to specific applications, (Skype and Steam for example).

Obviously adding it onto your machine won't distribute onto other machines and this cannot be achieved from a web page.

For example:

Skypes protocol handler would be:

```
<a href="skype:dordotky?userinfo">Skype</a>
```

Sadly, IE does not have one.

If you want to view the protocols - you'll find them in RegEdit- under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. For example the edge one will be under `microsoft-edge` folder, and you want to open the String option titled "URL Protocol". You'll find all available protocols on your system inside the key mentioned above.

Comment: no sir I think this false I can tell you why please open this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/microsoft-edge

Comment: @Kasp3rGhost If you read carefully, I said there's one protocol handler for Edge but there isn't one for IE. Just like when you install Skype, it adds a couple of protocol handlers to your system for you to use.

Comment: and you will note that the firefox or chroom ask the link will open in microsoft edge or yiu can open it on another progrme like iexplorer I choose iexplorer and I run it can I make the iexplorer came out with the application sujtion to open

Comment: Yeah.. that's the browser implementation. It gives you a choice called a browser prompt. This is only achievable using the said handlers. You can not make an automatic choice for the user either using client side scripting.

Comment: thanks man but can you tell me or give me a link what I can run from browser handlers please

Comment: @Kasp3rGhost You're welcome. Please see the edited last paragraph on my answer. That will tell you where to find them.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't an existing protocol handler for IE, you can easily create one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)