# How to force link opening on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm providing a link in of my chatbot texts which contains an url to an web app that only works properly when using IE.

This happens on a chatbot which is used only on Google Chrome. So when I link my user to the external website it opens up a new tab on Chrome and I need it to force opening on IE.

...a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.mywebsite.com/">Register

only works with Edge.

I need it to open with IE even if I'm setting the tag on Chrome.

`<a href="https://consorcio.sicredi.com.br/" target="_blank">Intranet Consórcio</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's not such a way to force the link opening in IE using only html. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958426/how-to-open-link-in-internet-explorer-using-html-or-any-browser-language), we could see that Microsoft Edge has a "URL Protocol" so we can open the link in Edge using `href="microsoft-edge:https://www.mywebsite.com/"`. If you want to force it opening in IE, you'll need to [add a protocol handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl/41749105#41749105) to the registry.

If you're the developer of the website which only works properly in IE, I think the easiest way is to alert a warning reminding the user to use IE when opening the website.