# Blazor Server - How launch IE browser from client machine

Tags: asp.net-core, internet-explorer, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have new Blazor Server application running in EDGE, which need to launch another old application in IE. How we can launch IE browser with a URL from Blazor Server application running in client machine? I used JavaScript previously during asp.net time with window.open. But there's no guarantee that IE going to open with window.open()

Comment: You can't, in a browser (such as Edge), instruct the browser to open a URL in a different browser (IE).

Comment: I agree with the answer below. We need to create a URL protocol so that we can use it in JavaScript to open IE. We can't directly open IE from Edge in code. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<A HREF="microsoft-ie:http://www.itworld.com/blog/readme-file">Open README file with IE</A>
```

Learn more:

```
<A HREF="microsoft-edge:http://www.itworld.com/blog/readme-file">Open README file with Edge</A>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958628/3728901

https://www.computerworld.com/article/3008858/how-to-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app