# Open specific browser onClick (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have researched before asking,

I found how to detect browser and take the value from the react context but now i am wondering if its possible to create a link which will check if specific browser is installed and if it is open the url in the new browser

Thanks.

Comment: possible dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881383/can-i-force-a-link-to-open-in-a-specific-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I force a link to open in a specific browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881383/can-i-force-a-link-to-open-in-a-specific-browser)